# Div not accurately responsive in iPad

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, response

I am having an issue with the web page display on iPad. The last div jumps out at the bottom when viewed in iPad (landscape mode).  See screenshot below

[image: Website Screenshot]

Here is the CSS.

```
div .container-home
{
    float: left;
    width: 290px !important;
    padding: 20px;
}

img.section-icon
{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 150px;
    max-height: 150px;
}

h2.section-head
{
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
    font-size: 22px;
}

p.section-description
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Many thanks!

Comment: can you add your HTML code too

Comment: You should add your HTML to your Question for context. You will have to use either media queries to target specific viewports and devices https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries and/or adjust your CSS to use percentages or viewport units. for each box.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including a viewport?
Its because of float left and the width of them together is more than the display. You define their width for 290px and also a padding of 20px which means they're 330px and you will need a display width of 1320px at least.

Try using a gridsystem for them or give them a width value in per cent.
If you don't know what gridsystem to use, I recommend Skeleton because it is very light.

EDIT: Don't use !important because then you cannot change the value anymore !important will overwrite any other rule

Answer (score 0):

Don't use hard value for width, example

```
div .container-home
{
    float: left;
    width: 20% !important;
    padding: 20px;
}

img.section-icon
{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 150px;
}

h2.section-head
{
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
    font-size: 22px;
}

p.section-description
{
    text-align: center;
}
```